# Generic type in Groovy getAt method

Tags: generics, groovy

I am trying to implement in Groovy MultiMap myself, using attached Code. I would prefer to use Java Generics. But I have problem with getAt(K k) method.

Method get() works without problems. But if I use getAt() from Main class:

println consPersonsOld.getAt('1111')

calling gatAt method of MultiMap:

```
class MultiMap<K,V> {
    private Map<K,List<V>> map

    public List<V> get(K k){
        if(map.containsKey(k)){
            return (map[k])
        }else{
            return([])
        }
    }

    //Instead of [k]
    public List<V> getAt(K k) {
        if(map.containsKey(k)){
            return (map[k])
        }else{
            return([])
        }
    }
}
```

I will get attached error:

Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: 1111 for class: com.tcc.util.MultiMap
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at com.tcc.GroAiaAdd3Main.main(GroAiaAdd3Main.groovy:84)

Apparently the code does problem with Generics type K, as when I replace K with String, everything is OK....
Do you have some idea, how to fix this problem?

Comment: how do you initialize the instance?

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint...

Comment: Originally in the constructor was just map = [:]
Current constructor works:

public MultiMap(){
   //map = [:]
   map = new HashMap<K,List<V>>()
}